# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc while compiling with makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

Context first: I have a header (event.h), a program called event.c, and the main program main.c. This program will be compiled, generating first a object program (event.o), then a static library (libevent.a) in a separate folder, and then the executable program work1.exe

To do this I created this makefile:

```
work1 : main.c libevent.a
    gcc -static main.c -L./lib -levent -o work1 -Wall

event.o: event.c
gcc -c event.c -Wall

libevent.a: event.o
ar rcs lib/libevento.a event.o 

clean: 
rm work1 *.o
```

The result of executing the makefile leads to this error:

```
 $ make
 gcc -c event.c -Wall
 ar rcs lib/libevent.a event.o 
 gcc -static main.c -L./lib -levent -o work1 -Wall
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 make: *** [work1] Error 1
```

Any idea what is going on here? Is there a way to compiling this without installing anything?

Comment: `ar rcs lib/libevento.a event.o` <- typo here or in the actual makefile?

Comment: It would appear as if you don't have the c libraries required for static linking. What platform are you compiling this on?

Comment: In this moment i'm compiling with CentOS. The same program was tested with Ubuntu and it worked.

Comment: Try installing the glibc static libraries -  `yum install glibc-static`. If that doesn't work, your `LIBRARY_PATH` more than likely does not include the location of `libc.a` (although I would assume `-L./lib` would have that...)

Comment: Or try `gcc main.c -L./lib -l event -o work -Wall`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The specific error is the following line:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
```

The linker cannot find the C libraries required for statically linking your library. You can try and see if `libc.a` already exists on your system by calling `locate libc.a`. If this returns, add an appropriate library flag pointing to the directory that includes `libc.a`.

If `libc.a` is not installed, you unfortunately need to install the library if you want to compile your library statically. Since you stated you are on CentOS, you should be able to accomplish this with `yum install glibc-static`.