# Compiling vim with statically linked python support in a non-standard path configuration

Tags: python, c, gcc, vim

I'm currently trying to compile `vim` on a Fedora 20 machine with a particularly exotic setup:

- No root access
- `python2` and `python3` manually compiled and installed in `~/.local` correctly working (after exporting the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).
- `zsh` as shell
- `gcc` version `4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7) (GCC)`

If I configure the compiling process as:

```
./configure --with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp --enable-python3interp --prefix=$HOME/.local
```

and then `make && make install`, `vim` is correctly compiled with `+python/dyn +python3/dyn`.

```
vim --version | grep python
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +wildignore
```

but, inside vim, `:echo has('python')` returns a `0` (and the [MatchTagAlways](https://github.com/Valloric/MatchTagAlways) complains about that in facts...).

So I told to myself, let's try to force the statically linked installation:

```
export LDFLAGS=-static
./configure --with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp --enable-python3interp --prefix=$HOME/.local
```

ends just a little bit after the configuring command:

```
configure: creating cache auto/config.cache
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/students/rm_16_17/dibattista/build/vim/src':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/fXBBtNsj) the full `configure.log`. The relevant line should be:

```
configure:3027: gcc   -static conftest.c  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

that I cannot really decrypt. It seems that `gcc` does not has the `-static` flag. Is that the issue?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to compile `vim` instead of getting it from the repo?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yep. The `vim` installed in the system has not `+clipboard` feature. (And I have not root access)

Comment: Take a look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/194747/how-to-install-vim-with-clipboard-support-on-fedora). It might be good enough for you... Or.. you are saying there is no `vim` on this system at all, and you can't install it from the repo?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks. The problem is that I have no root access.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024978/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lc-while-compiling-with-makefile) this seems (unfortunately) related.

Comment: Not having clipboard support may actually be a good thing if you are a student.

Comment: @romainl Well. I'm not a student (I mean, not technically. Whoever stops to learn in life?). I'm at work where 90% of colleagues use gui textEditor while I'm used to `vim` so the sysadmin does not want to change machines config just for me... T.T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end what I was missing was a flag when compiling Python to compile it as a shared library `--enable-shared`.

As a reminder: always read all the `INSTALL` instructions :)