# Having cannot find error while making file

Tags: opencv, makefile, g++

while I making the file, the error comes and I don't know how to fix this.

```
$ make libcv.so 
g++ -fPIC -o libcv.so --shared src/cv.cpp -I/home/fzehua/torch/install/include/THC -I/home/fzehua/torch/install/include/TH -I/home/fzehua/torch/install/include -L/home/fzehua/torch/install/lib -lluaT -lTH `pkg-config --libs opencv` 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcufft
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnpps
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnppi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnppc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libcv.so] Error 1
```

The Makefile write as follows:

```
PREFIX=$(HOME)/torch/install
CUDA=/usr/local/cuda
CFLAGS=-I$(PREFIX)/include/THC -I$(PREFIX)/include/TH -I$(PREFIX)/include
LDFLAGS_NVCC=-L$(PREFIX)/lib -Xlinker -rpath,$(PREFIX)/lib -lluaT -lTHC -lTH -lpng
LDFLAGS_CPP=-L$(PREFIX)/lib -lluaT -lTH `pkg-config --libs opencv`

libcv.so: src/cv.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -o libcv.so --shared src/cv.cpp $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS_CPP)
```

Comment: Do you have `libcufft.so` in `LDPATH`?

Comment: I found `libcufft.so` in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Why it search in `/usr/bin/ld` path?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is mentioned in [/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc while compiling with makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024978/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lc-while-compiling-with-makefile).

First I located the lib*.so by `locate lib*.a`, then added the path in `LDFLAGS_CPP` by `-L$(mypath)/lib`. It works.