# Undefined reference to 'printf' in C program

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld

I am trying to understand some `gcc` features like `__attribute__`, more precisely, how to use the `__attribute__((__section__("foo")))` for allocating data/code in specific memory locations.

My setup

## align.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
//Align some ints
#define BYTES 16
#define __weird_thing __attribute__((__section__("weird.data")))
int __weird_thing *bootstrap;
int a __attribute__((aligned(BYTES))) = 1;
int b __attribute__((aligned(BYTES))) = 2;
int c = 3;
int d __attribute__((aligned(BYTES))) = 4;


int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
        extern a, b, c, d;
        int *p = &a;
        printf(" a = %p \n", &a);
        printf(" sizof(a) = %d\n", sizeof(a));
        printf("__alignof__ = %d\n", __alignof__(a));
        printf(" p = %p \n\n", p);

        printf(" b = %p \n", &b);
        printf(" sizof(b) = %d\n", sizeof(b));
        printf("__alignof__ = %d\n", __alignof__(b));
        p = p + (BYTES / sizeof(int));
        printf(" p = %p \n\n", p);

        printf(" c = %p \n", &c);
        printf(" sizof(c) = %d\n", sizeof(c));
        printf("__alignof__ = %d\n", __alignof__(c));
        p = p + sizeof(b) / sizeof(int) ;
        printf(" p = %p \n\n", p);

        long unsigned int alignment;
        for(;(alignment=( (long unsigned int) p) & (BYTES << 1 )- 1 ,    printf("alignment = %p\n",alignment), alignment  != 0 ) ; p++);
        printf(" d = %p \n", &d);
        printf(" sizof(d) = %d\n", sizeof(d));
        printf("__alignof__ = %d\n", __alignof__(d));
        printf(" p = %p \n\n", p);
}
```

## include/imposible.h

```
int imposible(void);
```

## imposible.c

```
#include<imposible.h>
extern unsigned long int base;
int imposible(void)
{
        base++;
        return (int) &base;
}
```

## ld.lds

```
SECTIONS
{
        . = 0x10000;
        weird.data : { *(weird.data) }
        base = .;
}
```

## Problem

Whenever I try to link, it fails with undefined references

```
dudarev@Test-Sandbox section $ gcc -c align.c -o align.o
dudarev@Test-Sandbox section $ gcc -c -I include/ imposible.c -o imposible.o
imposible.c: In function ‘imposible’:
imposible.c:6:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  return (int) &base;
     ^

dudarev@Test-Sandbox section $ ld -T ld.lds align.o imposible.o -o a.out
align.o: In function `main':
align.c:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `printf'
align.c:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `printf'
align.c:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `printf'
align.c:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `printf'
align.c:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `printf'
align.o:align.c:(.text+0x8d): more undefined references to `printf' follow
```

As I undestand it does not find `printf`, meaning that `stdio` wasn't linked.
I installed `glibc-static` following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024978/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lc-while-compiling-with-makefile) stackoverflow question and tried `-lc` switch with `ld` which ended up in

```
dudarev@Test-Sandbox section $ ld -lc -T ld.lds align.o imposible.o -o a.out
ld: cannot find -lc
```

What am I missing people?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try running gcc on the same file (instead of ld) with verbose flag `-v` and see all the flags being passed to `ld` (or `collect2`).

Comment: Also unrelated but `return (int) &base;`. Why?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, here is the output https://pastebin.com/3w8Y4b62

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, for the unrelated, as stated above, I am learning, I'm trying to retrieve the section pointer address using base.

Comment: What makes you think casting a pointer to `int` will give you the section pointer (whatever that is) ?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, is this question something to do with my problem? I am trying to learn how the computer allocates the code into sections using linker scripts, this technique is used by linux as far as I understand to initialise code and free that memory afterwards. I am just trying to reproduce somehow this behaviour, This will help me  understand better how the operating system loads. Again, what I am trying to achieve is out the scope of this question. The question itself remains open.

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-LMA.html

Comment: `dudarev@Test-Sandbox section $ gcc -I include/ -lc -v align.c imposible.c -T ld.lds -o a.out` what I meant is use gcc to normally link them up, without your custom linker script. You will be able to see what gcc links up normally. In one of those library files you will find printf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding this problem:

*imposible.c:6:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  return (int) &base;*

This is because 'base' is type: `long int` and the return type for the `imposible()` function is: `int`

the file `align.c` causes the compiler to output LOTS of warnings, all of which should be corrected.

the file: `ld.lds` is missing several necessary statements.

The missing statements of `ld.lds` is why the `printf()` function cannot be found

here is a corrected version of the `align.c` file

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Align some ints
#define BYTES 16

#define weird_thing __attribute__((__section__("weird.data")))
int weird_thing *bootstrap;

int a __attribute__((aligned(BYTES))) = 1;
int b __attribute__((aligned(BYTES))) = 2;
int c = 3;
int d __attribute__((aligned(BYTES))) = 4;


int main( void )
{
        extern int a;
        extern int b;
        extern int c;
        extern int d;
        int *p = &a;
        printf(" a = %p \n", (void*)&a);
        printf(" sizof(a) = %lu\n", sizeof(a));
        printf("__alignof__ = %lu\n", __alignof__(a));
        printf(" p = %p \n\n", p);

        printf(" b = %p \n", &b);
        printf(" sizof(b) = %lu\n", sizeof(b));
        printf("__alignof__ = %lu\n", __alignof__(b));
        p = p + (BYTES / sizeof(int));
        printf(" p = %p \n\n", p);

        printf(" c = %p \n", &c);
        printf(" sizof(c) = %lu\n", sizeof(c));
        printf("__alignof__ = %lu\n", __alignof__(c));
        p = p + sizeof(b) / sizeof(int) ;
        printf(" p = %p \n\n", p);

        long unsigned int alignment;
        for( ;
             (alignment = (long unsigned int) p) &
             ((BYTES << 1 )- 1) && alignment != 0 ;
             p++)
        {
             printf("alignment = %p\n", (void*)alignment);
        }

        printf(" d = %p \n", &d);
        printf(" sizof(d) = %lu\n", sizeof(d));
        printf("__alignof__ = %lu\n", __alignof__(d));
        printf(" p = %p \n\n", p);
}
```

compiling/linking of just the `align.c` file then running yields the following: (on my linux computer, without the `ld.lds` file)

```
a = 0x602070 
 sizof(a) = 4
__alignof__ = 16
 p = 0x602070 

 b = 0x602080 
 sizof(b) = 4
__alignof__ = 16
 p = 0x602080 

 c = 0x602084 
 sizof(c) = 4
__alignof__ = 4
 p = 0x602084 

alignment = 0x602084
alignment = 0x602088
alignment = 0x60208c
alignment = 0x602090
alignment = 0x602094
alignment = 0x602098
alignment = 0x60209c
 d = 0x602090 
 sizof(d) = 4
__alignof__ = 16
 p = 0x6020a0
```

Note: the `align.c` file has the `main()` function, which does not call any of the other posted functions, such as `imposible()`

Comment: could you please point out what necessary statements are missing inside the linker script and why they are necessary to be able to access printf?

Comment: @Ruso_x, the .lds file must include the library that is 'stand alone' and contains an implementation of the 'printf()' function