# Linker error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, clang

I am trying to compile [this code](https://github.com/pq-crystals/kyber) for some time. Specifically, I am trying to compile the avx2 code using the given mac. However, I am always getting the following error.
I have looked up a lot but unable to find a solution. I will be very glad if you help me to find a solution.

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make: *** [test/test_kyber] Error 1

gcc version

> gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)
>
> Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
> warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Clang version :

> clang version 3.4.2 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot2-final)
>
> Target: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
>
> Thread model: posix

Output running the make command.

> /usr/bin/gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse2avx -mavx2 -march=native -static -o test/test_kyber kyber.c poly.c polyvec.c fips202.o fips202x4.c precomp.c ntt.c verify.c indcpa.c consts.c kex.c nttlevels0t4.s nttlevels5t7.s mul_coefficients.s polyvec_pointwise_acc.s poly_add.s poly_sub.s cbd.s poly_freeze.s crypto_stream_aes256ctr.c keccak4x/KeccakP-1600-times4-SIMD256.o randombytes.c test/test_kyber.c
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make: *** [test/test_kyber] Error 1

Comment: well, that's a make fail. *scnr* ... but to be serious, `cannot find -lc` sounds like a serious problem with your toolchain installation ... are you even able to compile **anything** on that machine?

Comment: Usually, I use gcc. And it works all the time.

Comment: Well, the Makefile in your linked project is hard-wired to `clang` for a specific set of input files (no idea why), so does `clang` work at all on your machine?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thank you for your help. I don't use clang much. But As you said, I just wrote a simple "hello world" and compiled using clang. It worked fine.

Comment: Ok, this is strange then ... can you give enough context of your output to show which **command** actually failed?

Comment: @FelixPalmen I have attached a picture.

Comment: Sounds like someone forgot an argument somewhere and it's taking "-lc" as a filename.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Was `CC='gcc -v'` any help?

Comment: Specifically `make -n` output ?

Comment: @TobySpeight I have added the output.

Comment: @TobySpeight the result after using gcc -v is here. http://txt.do/d6md7

Comment: @Mischa The "make -n" compiles but generates no output file. The output of "make -n " command is here. http://txt.do/d6mdy

Comment: DO NOT POST LINKS.  post the actual text as EDITS to your question.

Comment: `make -n` does not execute a compile; it prints the commands that `make` would have executed. In this case, the last line is peculiar:

`/usr/bin/gcc ... -o test/speed kyber.c ... cpucycles.c test/speed.`

This is trying to create test/speed by compiling several .c and .s files and then linking kyber.o ... cpucycles.o AND test/speed. Which is circular and guaranteed to cause some problem. Your makefile possibly lists `$@` at the end of the action, as a dependency of something it shouldn't, or in a variable setting. If test/speed already exists, its dependency on libc.so may be the problem.

Comment: @Mischa Even if I disable the compilation of speed.c. I am getting the same error.

Comment: Small update, I tried to build the code in my laptop, and it worked fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc while compiling with makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16024978/608639).

Answer (score 1):

thanks a lot for your help and time. I understood the problem. The makefile adds a -static flag, but on our office machines we don't have static libc.a. Hence, the error "cannot find -lc". I removed the static flag and it works fine for now. 
I think we don't need a static libc.a, but I will have to check more closely.

Comment: Expecting a static `libc`?  That's pretty badly broken.  Linking statically to `libc` is generally a bad idea.  Since `libc` is the interface to the system, any system update can possibly break a program linked statically to `libc`, if, for example, a system call changes.

Comment: Indeed. I don't know why the authors added the static flag.