# Cannot install atari-py on RedHat Enterprise server with c compiler broken error

Tags: python, linux, cmake, redhat, openai-gym

I am trying to install atari-py of openai gym module and i get the below errors:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Check for working C compiler: /bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /bin/cc -- broken
CMake Error at /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):

The C compiler "/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

  Change Dir: /tmp/pip-install-x2v7as8m/atari-py/atari_py/ale_interface/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

  Run Build Command:"/bin/gmake" "cmTC_d4bba/fast"
  gmake[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/pip-install-x2v7as8m/atari-py/atari_py/ale_interface/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
  /bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_d4bba.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_d4bba.dir/build
  gmake[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/pip-install-x2v7as8m/atari-py/atari_py/ale_interface/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
  Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d4bba.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
  /bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_d4bba.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /tmp/pip-install-x2v7as8m/atari-py/atari_py/ale_interface/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
  Linking C executable cmTC_d4bba
  /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_d4bba.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
  /bin/cc      -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_d4bba.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_d4bba
  /bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../libc.so when searching for -lc
  /bin/ld: skipping incompatible //lib/libc.so when searching for -lc
  /bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libc.so when searching for -lc
  /bin/ld: cannot find -lc
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  gmake[2]: *** [cmTC_d4bba] Error 1
  gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/pip-install-x2v7as8m/atari-py/atari_py/ale_interface/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
  gmake[1]: *** [cmTC_d4bba/fast] Error 2
  gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/pip-install-x2v7as8m/atari-py/atari_py/ale_interface/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'




CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also "/tmp/pip-install-x2v7as8m/atari-py/atari_py/ale_interface/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/tmp/pip-install-x2v7as8m/atari-py/atari_py/ale_interface/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [build] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/pip-install-x2v7as8m/atari-py/atari_py/ale_interface'
Could not build atari-py: Command '['make', 'build', '-C', 'atari_py/ale_interface', '-j', '47']' returned non-zero exit status 2.. (HINT: are you sure cmake is installed? You might also be missing a library. Atari-py requires: zlib [installable as 'apt-get install zlib1g-dev' on Ubuntu].)
```

The below are my system details.

Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
conda 4.5.11
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56)

The most alarming thing is that it says c compiler is broken. Cmake is already installed using

```
yum install cmake
```

as well as

```
conda install cmake
```

Updated after installing glibc-static.

The new errors are below:

```
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec2483823887

/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2483823887.dir/link.txt --verbose=1

/bin/cc CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2483823887.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o
cmTryCompileExec2483823887 -rdynamic

/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../crt1.o' is incompatible
with i386:x86-64 output

/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../crti.o' is incompatible
with i386:x86-64 output

/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../crtn.o' is incompatible
with i386:x86-64 output

/bin/ld: dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `strcmp' with pointer equality in
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libc.a(strcmp.o)'
can not be used when making an executable; recompile with -fPIE and relink
with -pie

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

gmake[2]: *** [cmTryCompileExec2483823887] Error 1

gmake[2]: Leaving directory
`/tmp/pip-install-3ilk445h/atari-py/atari_py/ale_interface/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


gmake[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec2483823887/fast] Error 2

gmake[1]: Leaving directory
`/tmp/pip-install-3ilk445h/atari-py/atari_py/ale_interface/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

Comment: Possibly related to [/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc while compiling with makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16024978/608639) and [Linker error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45938875/608639).

Comment: This fixed the -lc errors but i am getting errors related to crt1.o' is incompatible
      with i386:x86-64 output

Comment: *"... errors related to crt1.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64..."* Maybe you need to remove `-m32` somewhere? Or maybe add `-m64` somewhere? Hard to say without seeing error messages.

Comment: I have updated the questions with new errors

Comment: I think you should read the error messages and then perform a quick search.

Comment: I did. None of the solutions work for Red Hat enterprise